# Why sort(), arrange() ignores special characters in R. How to suppress it?

Tags: r

When I sort the strings in R, I noticed that it ignores the special characters such as ~, [, etc.
For example

```
> sort(c('~a','b','c'))
[1] "~a" "b"  "c"
```

while I was expecting the following results since '~' is ordered higher in the ASCII table

```
[1] "b", "c", "~a"
```

I would like a results that keeps the ASCII order. Is there a way to enforce that in sort() as well as arrange(). I am particular wanting to find a solution for arrange() because I am applying the sorting in a data frame.

Comment: Did you try this `sort(c('~a','b','c'), method = "radix")`?

Comment: Thanks, method='radix' worked for sort(). But it didnt work for arrange() somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ignoring the ASCII order. It seems like ~ indeed comes before the alphabet. See the following.

```
> v=c("a", "~b", "c")
> sort(v)
[1] "~b" "a"  "c"
```

Comment: No, I am still getting "a"  "~b" "c" on my computer